# create spans with different classes dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Based on `text` variable which contains two separate sentences, I want to use `innerHTML` method and add a bunch of `spans` into the `container` like this:

```js
const text = "this is, the [or here] first one. / this is the |second string is colored| (in here) |one| after this.";

const result = ''
        + '<span class="string">this is, the </span>'
        + '<span class="box-bracket">[</span>'
        + '<span class="string">or here</span>'
        + '<span class="box-bracket">]</span>'
        + '<span class="string"> first one.</span>'
        + '<span class="separator"> / </span>'
        + '<span class="string">this is the </span>'
        + '<span class="colored">second string is colored </span>'
        + '<span class="round-bracket">(</span>'
        + '<span class="string">in here</span>'
        + '<span class="round-bracket">)</span>'
        + '<span class="colored"> one</span>'
        + '<span class="string"> after this.</span>'


const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.box-bracket   { color: #ff8800; }
.separator     { color: #00e366; }
.colored       { color: #1e00e3; }
.round-bracket { color: #e300d4; }
```

```html
<div id ="container"></div>
```

So far I created `result` manually to show you how I want this to be but I want to create `result` dynamically in the code.

As you see there are 4 different colors for separator (there will be a single separator only) brackets and colored text which is part of the string trapped between `|` signs and etc...

I tried a lot but as a beginner I think I need a hand to figure out a good solution...

The only condition is there may be none of the signs and symbols just like a simple string could be... and in that situation we have not any changes...

Comment: you don't need the first and second `span` (and all other span without colors), are they usefull for something else ?

Comment: It was a mistake sorry I'll edit that...

Comment: just edited....

Comment: so there is still `<span>` without `class="..`, why ?

Comment: They could get a `class="string"` of course I wanted to emphasis the spans which I want to assign a color to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a glitch in the space following the colored class, but I resolved it.

```js
const text = "this is, the [or here] first one. / this is the |second string is colored| (in here) |one| after this."
  ;
let txtCuts       = text.split(/(\[)|(\])|(\()|(\))|(\|)|( \/ )/).filter(x=>!!x)
  , result        = ''
  , lostSpace     = ''
  , followedSpace = false
  , colored       = false
  ;
txtCuts.forEach((txt,i)=>
  {
  switch (txt) 
    {
    case '[':
    case ']':
      result += '<span class="box-bracket">'+txt+'</span>'
      break;
    case '(':
    case ')':
      result += '<span class="round-bracket">'+txt+'</span>'
      break;
    case ' / ':
      result += '<span class="separator"> / </span>'
      break;
    case '|':
      result += colored ?  '</span>' : '<span class="colored">'
      colored = !colored
      break;
    case ' ':
      if (followedSpace) followedSpace = false
      else               lostSpace     = ' '
      break;
    default:
      followedSpace = ((i+2<txtCuts.length) && txtCuts[i+1]==='|' && txtCuts[i+2]===' ' )
      let plusTxt =  lostSpace + txt + (followedSpace?' ':'')
      result     += colored ? plusTxt : '<span class="string">' + plusTxt + '</span>' 
      lostSpace   = ''
      nextSpace   = false
      break;
    }
  })
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = result;

// control
// txtCuts.forEach((txt,i)=>
//   {
//   console.log(`__${txt}__${'_'.repeat(25-txt.length)}`, (txt===' ')? 's' : '_', `${'_'.repeat(10)}`, i)  
//   })
```

```css
.box-bracket   { color: #ff8800; }
.separator     { color: #00e366; }
.colored       { color: #1e00e3; }
.round-bracket { color: #e300d4; }
```

```html
<div id ="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.replace()` and a regular expresions for every option.

```js
let text = "this is, the [or here] first one. / this is the |second string is colored| (in here) |one| after this.";
const regexp1 = /\[/gm;
const regexp2 = /\]/gm;
const regexp3 = /\|(.*?)\|/gm;
const regexp4 = /\//gm;
const regexp5 = /\(/gm;
const regexp6 = /\)/gm;

text = text.replace(regexp4,"<span class='separator'>/</span>"); // This is first for minimize the </element>
text = text.replace(regexp1,"<span class='box-bracket'>[</span>");
text = text.replace(regexp2,"<span class='box-bracket'>]</span>");
text = text.replace(regexp3,"<span class='colored'>$1</span>");
text = text.replace(regexp5,"<span class='round-bracket'>(</span>");
text = text.replace(regexp6,"<span class='round-bracket'>)</span>");

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = text
```

```css
.box-bracket   { color: #ff8800; }
.separator     { color: #00e366; }
.colored       { color: #1e00e3; }
.round-bracket { color: #e300d4; }
```

```html
<div id ="container"></div>
```

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for string between two | signs which is supposed to be colored...